# Magento 2: "regionId is a required field."

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout

Im using Magento 2.2.1 and I try to customize checkout module. In order to remove unnecessary fields I added/overrided file in:

> app/design/frontend/custom_template/template1/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

with:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <!-- The name of the form the field belongs to -->
                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!--Remove fields-->
                                                            <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region</item>
                                                                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Unnecessary fields disappeared (even telephone stop being required) but on the last step of checkout (http://store.com/checkout/#payment) when I click button "Place Order" i get

> "regionId is a required field"

and I cant complete the order.

How Can I disable this field entirely?

Comment: I added your <item name="default" xsi:type="string">abc</item>  into <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array"> but still the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the  Admin side, click the `Stores => General => State Option`.
From the list, unselect all the selected countries. Save config, clear your cache and refresh.

Comment: It seems impossibe to unselect all selected countries. If I unselect all countries and save configuration then it leaves last configuration. I was able  at least to select one country. This time on checkout  get: Some addresses cannot be used due to country-specific configurations.

Comment: I sniffed queries from M2 into DB. And I saw that require region is set in core_config_data table. So I changed proper value directly: UPDATE core_config_data SET value=NULL where config_id=12; . Still doesnt work... Still get "Some addresses cannot be used due to country-specific configurations"