# Magento 2: Getting “regionId is a required field.” when I click button "Place Order"

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, state

I am Getting

> regionId is a required field.

when I click button "Place Order" on the checkout page

I tried this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/205232/65951 and it worked but then the state is not being saved after placing an order. I want to save state info too.

Comment: Stores => General => State Option => Allow to Choose State if It is Optional for Country =>YES Save config, clear your cache and refresh.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the state at the [image]